# Set Text Box equal to Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a query in an Access Db that counts the number of observations that meet a certain criteria as defined by two comboboxes. The query works fine, and I can get the result of the query to display and update live with the comboboxes using subforms, but the subforms are an extremely ugly way to represent a single number.

I would like to use a textbox to display that single number from the query instead of a subreport. I've tried inputting the SQL of the query into the Control Source and the Default Value, but no success.

After reading through the forum it appears I can write a function and then set my control source equal to that function.

Here is my VBA:

```
Public Function AdultCount()
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs=CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Count([name]) as [# Vars] from Masterdb where ((masterdb.year=[forms]![Masterform]![NavigationSubform].[form]![year]) and (masterdb.recipient=[forms]![Masterform]![NavigationSubform].[form]![recipient]) and (masterdb.group="adult"))")

AdultVar=rs!Result

rs.Close

Set rs=Nothing

End Function
```

I get "compile error: Expected:list separator or )"
and it highlights "adult" at the end of my SQL query.

I don't know why this isn't working. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error, and tell me if I'm even doing the right thing to get what I want?

edit:

I now have

```
Dim strSQL AS String

strSQL = "Select Count([name]) as [# Vars] from Masterdb where [year] = " & Me.NavigationSubform.year.value & " and [recipient] = " & Me.NavigationSubform.recipient.value & " and [group]='adult'"

Set rs=CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

AdultVar=rs![# Vars].Value

rs.Close

Set rs=Nothing

End Function
```

But the textbox reads "#Name?"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The double quotes for "adult" are throwing the error because you're closing and reopening a string without telling VB what to do with `adult"))")`. SQL needs single quotes anyway, so change it to 'adult' and the error will go away.

Comment: I did this and the error went away, but the text box just displays "Name?" instead of the data I want. I will try the other solution you provided.

Comment: Here: `AdultVar=rs!Result` The recordset does not include a field named *Result*. Try `AdultVar=rs![# Vars].Value` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A second option is to build your string first, like so:

```
Dim strSQL AS String

strSQL = "Select Count([name]) as [# Vars] from Masterdb where [year] = " & Me.NavigationSubform.year.value & " and [recipient] = " & Me.NavigationSubform.recipient.value & " and [group]='adult'"

Set rs=CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

If you're not familiar with using the Me keyword, do a bit of reading up as it will shorten your code and save you time.

Comment: So do I just enter this VBA within a function and then set the Control source of the text box I want equal to the above VBA or do I need to do more VBA?

Comment: Your function seems fine at first glance. Replace your `"rs="` line with my snippet, and fix the issue that @HansUp mentioned, and that should do it.

Comment: So I now have the above code plus the issue with AdultVar=rs...fixed but I'm still getting "#Name?" for the textbox. Any ideas?

Comment: Add a breakpoint early in your function so you can follow it. Then load the form, hit F8 when the VBA window pops back up, and hover on the variable names. You can watch what happens at each step to help narrow down the issue.